# Sort order of blob list in Azure

Tags: azure-blob-storage, collation

The [List Blobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135734.aspx) article on MSDN says that:

> Blobs are listed in alphabetical order in the response body, with upper-case letters listed first.

However, alphabetical ordering depend on which culture they're using, or is there a precise meaning of *alphabetical order* that they are implicitly referring to?

I want to know the exact ordering scheme. I'm guessing (and hoping) that they are using the ordinal (binary) sorting rules, equivalent to  [StringComparison.Ordinal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) in .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , you are right. It equals to [StringComparison.Ordinal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx) in .NET. All of the listed blobs are all encoded in UTF-16.And the list blob name rule is that comparing the 2 strings char by char. The small Unicode value is before the large one. It is the same rule with [StringComparison.Ordinal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx) in .NET.

Comment: Excellent. Do you have any official source to back this up?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed this info with the Azure team.

Comment: Great. Thank you.