# Getting latest folder from Azure Blob Storage container

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have created blob storage in azure.

Then have created container called as "MyReport"

Inside container "MyReport" I created 2 folders called as "Test" and "Live". Under both folders "Test" and "Live" there are many subfolders.

What I want is to get latest folder created by azure in those folders.

I tried the following:

```
StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey credentials = new  StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(accountName, accessKey);
CloudStorageAccount acc = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
CloudBlobClient client = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobDirectory container = client.GetBlobDirectoryReference(@"MyReport/Test");

var folders = container.ListBlobs().Where(b => b as CloudBlobDirectory != null).ToList();
```

In Folders variable I get many folders but I want to get the latest folder created by azure.

How to do this?

Comment: As such there're no folders in Azure Blob Storage. They are simply blob prefixes and are part of blob's name.

Comment: @GauravMantri so how to get latest blob prefix in azure context?

Comment: Are you following a pattern in naming the blobs?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes i am following pattern like DDMMYHYYHHMM-BuildVersion. BuildVersion is string like "1.4.2.123" . But i think its difficult to sort by it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 10/04:**

```
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("test1");
            CloudBlobDirectory myDirectory = cloudBlobContainer.GetDirectoryReference("test");
            var myfiles = myDirectory.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true, blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.All).Where(b => b as CloudBlockBlob != null);

            var my_lastmodified_blob = myfiles.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().OrderByDescending(b => b.Properties.LastModified).First();
            Console.WriteLine(my_lastmodified_blob.Parent.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.Segments.Last());
```

The result(there is a "/" at the end of the folder name, you can remove it as per your need):

[image]

---

As per this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288123/sort-order-of-blob-list-in-azure?answertab=active#tab-top), when list blobs, the blob is ordered by comparing blob's name char-by-char(ascending order).

So in your code, just use `ListBlobs` method, then use `.Last()` to fetch the latest one.

Sample code:

```
#other code

var myblob = container.ListBlobs().Last();
Console.WriteLine(((CloudBlockBlob)myblob).Name);
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: but i am searching for latest cloudblobdirectory_

Comment: i want lastmodified for cloudblob prefix and not cloudblob. I have container called "MyReport" and in that container i have 2 folders called "Test" and "Prod". In each of those folders i have many subfolders and i want to get lastmodified subfolder.

Comment: @James, if that's case, you can just get the last modified blob. And in the blob name, you can get the folder(the folder name and file name consists the blob name).

Comment: How to get it then because there is no LastModified property

Comment: My folder name is like DDMMYYYHHMM-1.3.5.2... Later there will be more folder like  DDMMYYYYHHMM-1.3.6.1... basically i create folder in DDMMYYYHHMM-BuildNumber

Comment: @James, can you help confirm one thing? when mentioned last-modified folder, do you mean you add a new file in that folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200388/discussion-between-james-and-ivan-yang).

Comment: There will be atleast one file in that folder

Answer (score 1):

Actually CloudBlobDirectory don't hold LastModified Date but within folder all CloudBlockBlob hold Last modified date. so We should decide based on inner files

Here is sample and its working for me

```
CloudBlobClient client = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = client.GetContainerReference(@"seleniumtestreports");
CloudBlobDirectory Directory = container.GetDirectoryReference("DevTests");
var BlobFolders = Directory.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlobDirectory>()        .Select(f => new { cloudBlobDirectory = f,LastModified = f.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().OrderByDescending(dd => dd.Properties.LastModified).FirstOrDefault().Properties.LastModified }).ToList();

var getLastestFolder = BlobFolders.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastModified).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

With some clue from @Ivan Yang, i found answer for this.

Clue was to use BlobRequest options. So this works for me

```
StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey credentials = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(accountName, accessKey);

        CloudStorageAccount acc = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);

        CloudBlobClient client = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobDirectory container = client.GetBlobDirectoryReference(@"MyReport/Test");

        BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions();
        options.UseFlatBlobListing = true;
        var listblob = container.ListBlobs(options);

        var latestFolderAzure = listblob.OfType<CloudBlob>().OrderBy(b => b.Properties.LastModifiedUtc).LastOrDefault()?.Parent.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
```